# Woocommerce deletes cart before adding new product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a pretty basic problem , I guess people working with woocommerce and wordpress would know how to solve this.

I have a customizable product the customer creates on a page, and then are able to add it to the cart.

The product and the add to cart button works fine so to say.

It add's the product - BUT it clears the cart before adding the newly customized product. Why does it do that ? And how can I avoid it - so it just add's another one to the cart before emptying the current one.

My add to cart button:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 )
```

My product creation:

```
function customcart() {

  if (isset($_POST["addcustomcarts"])) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'Design selv skilt',
      'post_content'  => '<div class="col-md-12">Dette er et design selv skilt, tjek egenskaber på produktet for at se hvad kunden har bestilt.</div>',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => 'product'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    $filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

    //Decode the string
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    //Save the image
    file_put_contents('img' . $product_ID . '.png', $unencodedData);

    if ( $product_ID ){
      wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'design-selv-skilte', 'product_cat' );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', $_POST["priceInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', $_POST["priceInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
      //add_post_meta($product_ID, '_manage_stock', 'yes' );    
      //add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock', '10' ); 
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_sku', 'designselvskilt-' . $product_ID );   
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_visibility', 'hidden' );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'tekst-paa-linje-1', $_POST["textInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'tekst-paa-linje-2', $_POST["text2Input"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'stoerrelse', $_POST["størrelseInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'form', $_POST["formInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'farve', $_POST["farveInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'type-skilt', $_POST["typeInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'fastgoering', $_POST["fastgøringInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'font', $_POST["fontInput"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'linje-1-font-size', $_POST["fontSizeLine1Input"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'linje-2-font-size', $_POST["fontSizeLine2Input"] );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'product_image_gallery', $_POST["img_val"]);
      add_post_meta($product_ID, 'product_image_url', 'img' . $product_ID . '.png');  
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
      $home = home_url();
      $url = $home . '/img' . $product_ID . '.png';
      $post_id = $product_ID;
      $desc = $_POST["textInput"];
      $image = media_sideload_image($url, $post_id, $desc, src );

              function getImageId( $image ) {
            // Split the $url into two parts with the wp-content directory as the separator
            $parsed_url  = explode( parse_url( WP_CONTENT_URL, PHP_URL_PATH ), $image );

            // Get the host of the current site and the host of the $url, ignoring www
            $this_host = str_ireplace( 'www.', '', parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) );
            $file_host = str_ireplace( 'www.', '', parse_url( $image, PHP_URL_HOST ) );

            // Return nothing if there aren't any $url parts or if the current host and $url host do not match
            if ( ! isset( $parsed_url[1] ) || empty( $parsed_url[1] ) || ( $this_host != $file_host ) ) {
                return;
            }

            // Now we're going to quickly search the DB for any attachment GUID with a partial path match
            // Example: /uploads/2013/05/test-image.jpg
            global $wpdb;

            $attachment = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE guid RLIKE %s;", $parsed_url[1] ) );

            // Returns null if no attachment is found
            return $attachment[0];
        }    

      set_post_thumbnail($post_id, getImageId( $image ));    

      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );

       wp_redirect( '/kurv' ); exit;

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the woocommerce support forums yet? You're much more likely to get an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution for this question, Matthew was pointing me in the right direction concerning the cart session but the code that worked for me was this :

So before adding product to cart I had to retrieve the current cart session.

```
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_from_session();
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not the only one to find that the cart needs to be initialized first to get consistent and expected behaviours from it:

- [How to properly initialize Woocommerce Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477698/how-to-properly-initialize-woocommerce-cart)

I would suggest that you consider getting in something like:

```
$woocommerce->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
```

To get things going so that you are not making and setting a new cart and over-writing the old one.

**Also**

I imagine that this could cause you problems down the road:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );
```

This is the same as putting

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, TRUE );
```

The reason being is that you are passing to the method the result of `$quantity=1` which is almost always going to be a success.

What you mean is:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, 1 );
```

However my guess is that you took the method signature which shows that the second parameter is optional and defaults to a value of integer one if left out in which case you could make it even simpler with:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID );
```

If you only want to pass variables then you need something like this

```
$quantity = 1;
// ... any other code
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity );
```

Comment: good suggestion, but it does not solve the issue, it still empties the cart before adding the new product regardless of which method I use that you suggest. Could it have something to do with the actual method I use , conflicting with theme functions or maybe cart sesseion  ?

Comment: I have been reading up on the class in question. It has methods for loading the session, starting a session and inspecting the cart contents. Furthermore a lot of the examples call the class statically (but not all) so I hesitate to make too many assumptions about what should be done when.

Comment: something worth mentioning is that if I add the customizable product first and the add regular products afterwards it works fine.

Comment: Got you, I think I know what the problem is. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I really believed that was it , but it doesen't seem to be the issue. Tried both with the function version and the stripped version placing $woocommerce->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true); directly on the template page and/or in the function.

Comment: This did the trick for me: $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_from_session();

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter for that

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);
function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) 
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: You saved me some time digging into the woocommerce hooks +1

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the values your passing to `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 )`

What about dumping the SQL it generates and attempt to run it, see if it returns any errors?

Comment: I have checked that, and it does add the product to the cart correctly , it just empties the cart before adding it - that's the issue.

Comment: dont want to teach you to such eggs, but just examine the query's being sent when the action is called and see which one is manipulating the DB incorrectly. Its either something being deleted/updated, or a new relation being created that's not joining to the past products, maybe being assigned a new basket ID. 
Maybe see if the past baskets contents is still accessible through the DB?